# Snakemake takes 90 s on WSL for test snakefile with very simple workload

Tags: conda, snakemake

### Context

I'm exploring snakemake to define my data analysis as a DAG and evaluate it reproducibly. I installed it in a separate environment on WSL2 on windows 10. Before working on my actual project I wanted to try it on a simple project to get some feeling for how it works.

I wanted to test using the shell and python on 3 txt files (2 columns of numbers, comma separated). A first rule copies the files as .csv to a separate folder 'intermediate', through a shell command. A second rule then loads a python script to read in the intermediate file and graph it using matplotlib. I want to run the python script in a separate conda environment. This is not strictly necessary for what I want to do, but I can see the benefits of it.

### Question

The DAG runs properly and outputs the files. However the rule involving conda/python takes 90 seconds. This seems unnecessary long, from command line I would expect this to run in a second or so. Do I do something wrong? Is something happening in the background that I'm not aware of? Even if it is necessary, I guess it would be easier to accept if I knew what is happening.

### What I've tried so far

- move project to WSL disk: first the project was running on the mounted c, but it turns out this is known to have [speed issues](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4197). So the project now lives in a subdirectory of my home directory.
- An env with numpy and matplotlib was created in .snakemake/conda/alphanumeric_env_name the first time I ran the snakefile. This took a while (a little longer than if you make the env manually with conda/mamba from the yml, as documented here) but the DAG worked with --use-conda. When running, the python rules still took long, and last thing the bash printed was `Activating conda environment: ../.snakemake/conda/a060898bb3a415a46236eba6c4b6b5fa_` So I figured it was the activation that took long.
- To check for this: installed numpy and pandas with conda in my snakemake env itself, and commented out the conda part of the rule. Using the snakemake environment itself is less ideal, but I could live with it. Still, very slow execution (see log below).

### Code

My snakefile looks as follows.

**workflow/snakefile**

```
samples = "first_data,second_data,third_data"

rule all:
    input:
        expand("graphs/{file}.png", file=samples.split(",")),


rule make_intermediate:
    input:
        "data/{file}.txt",
    output:
        "intermediate/{file}_shell.csv",
    shell:
        "cp {input[0]} {output[0]}"


rule make_graph:
    input:
        "intermediate/{file}_shell.csv",
    output:
        "graphs/{file}.png",
    # conda:
    #    "../envs/data_env.yaml"
    script:
        "../scripts/a_script.py"
```

with **a_script.py**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def make_graph(filename_in, filename_out):
    data = np.loadtxt(filename_in, delimiter=',')
    plt.figure()
    plt.title(filename_in)
    plt.plot(data[:, 0], data[:, 1])
    plt.savefig(filename_out)
    plt.close()
make_graph(snakemake.input[0], snakemake.output[0])
```

This is the relevant log (I do not use conda to open a separate environment here). with `snakemake -c 4`

```
Select jobs to execute...
Execute 3 jobs...

[Wed Jan 17 19:58:26 2024]
localrule make_graph:
    input: intermediate/second_data_shell.csv
    output: graphs/second_data.png
    jobid: 3
    reason: Missing output files: graphs/second_data.png
    wildcards: file=second_data
    resources: tmpdir=/tmp

[Wed Jan 17 19:58:26 2024]
localrule make_graph:
    input: intermediate/first_data_shell.csv
    output: graphs/first_data.png
    jobid: 1
    reason: Missing output files: graphs/first_data.png
    wildcards: file=first_data
    resources: tmpdir=/tmp

[Wed Jan 17 19:58:26 2024]
localrule make_graph:
    input: intermediate/third_data_shell.csv
    output: graphs/third_data.png
    jobid: 5
    reason: Missing output files: graphs/third_data.png
    wildcards: file=third_data
    resources: tmpdir=/tmp

[Wed Jan 17 20:00:39 2024]
Finished job 1.
1 of 4 steps (25%) done
[Wed Jan 17 20:00:39 2024]
Finished job 3.
2 of 4 steps (50%) done
[Wed Jan 17 20:00:39 2024]
Finished job 5.
3 of 4 steps (75%) done
Select jobs to execute...
Execute 1 jobs...
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out the problem was at an unexpected place: the python script worked fast enough when I just asked it to print it. The problem was with there being no graphical backend in WSL. Adding the following at the top of `a_script.py` solved the problem.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
```

Comment: So what then was happening in OP? Was matplotlib blocking/waiting for a backend to respond?

Comment: yes, it was waiting after plt.figure(). Figured out the python script was actually starting quite fast, by adding print statements. My guess it was trying all possible backends before landing on Agg, which then worked. Which is why I got the actual output after that time.